# Complex storyboard, any issues?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new to storyboards. I want to start a project with some twists in the navigation.
This is the setup I want to create:

The first screen (let's call this one HOME) has some buttons/icons (for navigational purposes). When clicking on button 1, it goes to a segue with a UITableListView, where you can drill down several levels in other UITableListViews until you arrive at a detail view. Button 2 is very similar, when clicked you arrive in a UITableListView and can drill down again, and this is so for most buttons (some have more, other less levels to drill down).

So far nothing special, but I want to add a twist to the navigation to make things simpler and faster for the user: Each of the segues (except for the HOME screen), will have a 'Home' Button which brings you back to the first screen, the Home screen, so the user doesn't have to navigate back 'up'. (some sort of 'go to the top level in one tap').

When the user navigates down on button 1 for let's say 5 levels, and goes to the top level using 'Home', then navigates down some levels on another button (e.g. 3), and goes to 'Home' again using the 'Home button, then clicks on button 1 again, (s)he should arrive at level 5 again (avoiding the need to drill down again).

1) What do you think is the best way to implement this ? One  possible approach would be to have a home screen with the buttons and have multiple storyboards, one for each button, versus the one storyboard does all way.

Another approach would be to go with 1 storyboard but then this questions arise:

2) Isn't this introducing some kind of 'circular' navigation and memory issues on this . Is this correct ?

3) how to implement the home button, remember where to navigate back...

4) any other thoughts ?

The reason I want to have this button is that there are often quite some levels to drill down AND there is often the need to switch to another context(read other button on the home screen.

Comment: Would this be simpler if you started with a tab bar controller and used the tabs to choose among different drill-down stacks (navigation controllers) rather than your home screen buttons?

Comment: there would be no content on the screen, just the tab bar controllers...